# VBA List of Custom Datastructures

Tags: vba, list, excel, structure

One of the main problems in VBA are custom data structures and lists.
I have a loop which generates with each iteration multiple values.
So as an example:
Each loop iteration generates a string "name" an integer "price" and an integer "value".

In C# for example I'd create a class which can hold these three values and with each loop iteration I add the class object to a list.

How can I do the same thing in VBA if I want to store multiple sets of data when not knowing how many iterations the loop will have (I cant create an array with a fixed size)

Any ideas?

Comment: Add a class module from `Insert > Class Module`. You will need to then define properties with setter and getter subroutines/functions. Unlike .NET, VBA doesn't really have a constructor with parameters but for this I use a `Init(...)` subroutine with my parameters.

Comment: As an alternative to arrays, you can use a Collection variable to store the class objects (Dim MyCollection as Collection).

Answer (score 2):

The approach I use very frequently is to use a class and a collection. I also tend to use an interface model to make things more flexible. An example would look something like this:

**Class Module IFoo**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Create(ByVal Name as String, ByVal ID as String)

End Property

Public Property Get Name() as String

End Property

Public Property Get ID() as String

End Property
```

This enforces the pattern I want for my `Foo` class.

**Class Module Foo**

```
Option Explicit

Private Type TFoo
    Name as String
    ID as String
End Type

Private this as TFoo

Implements IFoo

Private Sub IFoo_Create(ByVal Name as String, ByVal ID as String)
    this.Name = Name
    this.ID = Name
End Sub

Private Property Get IFoo_Name() as String
    IFoo_Name = this.Name
End Property

Private Property Get IFoo_ID() as String
    IFoo_ID = this.ID
End Property
```

We get intellisense from the `Private Type TFoo : Private this as TFoo` where the former defines the properties of our container, the latter exposes them privately. The `Implements IFoo` allows us to selectively expose properties. This also allows you to iterate a `Collection` using an `IFoo` instead of a `Foo`. Sounds pointless until you have an `Employee` and a `Manager` where `IFoo_BaseRate` changes depending on employee type.

Then in practice, we have something like this:

**Code Module Bar**

```
Public Sub CollectFoo()
    Dim AllTheFoos as Collection
    Set AllTheFoos = New Collection

    While SomeCondition
        Dim Foo as IFoo
        Set Foo = New Foo

        Foo.Create(Name, ID)
        AllTheFoos.Add Foo
    Loop

    For each Foo in AllTheFoos
        Debug.Print Foo.Name, Foo.ID
    Next
End Sub
```

While the pattern is super simple once you learn it, you'll find that it is incredibly powerful and scalable if implemented properly. It also can dramatically reduce the amount of copypasta that exists within your code (and thus reduce debug time).

Answer (score 1):

You can use classes in VBA as well as in C#: [Class Module Step by Step](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa240810(v=vs.60).aspx) or [A Quick Guide to the VBA Class Module](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-class-modules/)

And to to the problem with the array: you can create an array with dynamic size like [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vba/vba_arrays.htm)

```
'Method 1 : Using Dim
Dim arr1()  'Without Size

'somewhere later -> increase a size to 1
redim arr1(UBound(arr1) + 1)
```

Comment: And how would you use a list.

Comment: I can't use an array because I dont have a fixed size of loop iterations

Comment: @user4042470 Initialise the array as `Dim lstArr() as MyClass` then redim with `ReDim lstArr(0 to 1024)`, or increase as required. Use an integer such as `Dim index as integer = 0` and increment this every time you add to the array. If you need to reduce the list then use `ReDim Preserve lstArr(0 to index - 1)`

Comment: You can borrow VBScript's [Dictionary](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176993.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or [Colection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525228%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) objects.  Just add a reference to VBS first (`Tools` >> `References...` >> `Windows Script Host Object Model`) or late bind.  Watch out, they're not as good as the .Net objects you are used to.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class - but if all you want to do is hold three bits of data together, I would define a Type structure. It needs to be defines at the top of an ordinary module, after option explicit and before any subs

```
Type MyType
 Name As String
 Price As Integer
 Value As Integer
End Type
```

And then to use it

```
Sub test()
Dim t As MyType
t.Name = "fred"
t.Price = 12
t.Value = 3


End Sub
```

Comment: Can you add Types to a collection?

Comment: IIRC, you can't add a `Type` to a `Collection` since it isnt an `Object`, and isnt a predefined type (string, long, bool, etc). You'd be better off using a class.